# Mass-Insert for a has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

User
<> Friendship <> 
Follower

```
user has_many :followers, through: :friendships
follower has_many :users, through: :friendships
```

I need to insert up to 500.000 "followers" and we have a lot of users. In total there will be a few million followers with approx 500 users.

i already removed everything into a single transaction, which saves a little bit of time - but defenitely not enough

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  new_usernames.each do |name|
    follower = followers.find_or_create_by! username: name
    # TODO
    # do someting with follower
  end
end
```

i had the idea to make it a raw single-sql-statement, something similar to:

`ìnsert into followers(usernames) values(#{account.followed_by.join(","))`

(the username is unique, so mysql will prevent from double accounts)

obviously then i miss all the associations. then i thought i can do something like

`DELETE FROM friendships WHERE user_id = 1337`
and then mass insert all friendships again.

`INSERT INTO friendships VALUES (account.followed_by.map{|x| "(1337, #{x})"})`

obviously then i can't track any additional informations at the friendship.

are there any other possibilites?

Comment: Are followers and users different models? What is `account` in this example, its a User, right?

Comment: yes, different models. account is actually just an object that represents an instagram user. followed_by is then just an array of user_names. i changed the code a little to make it rad easier